Post on a public Facebook group without notifying friends
I am aware that Facebook shows your comments on friends' news feeds / timelines, even if they don't follow the group or page the comment was left on, as long as the comment is publicly accessible to them.
For example:

How to remove "[Friend] Liked this post" from my Facebook news feed?
Is there a way to control whose news feeds my likes, comments, and photos I'm tagged in, appear on?

Because of this, I am always afraid to leave comments.
I would like to make a Post (not comment) on a public group without my non-member friends seeing that I left the Post. Is there a way to do that, or will this be the case by default?
I would not like to leave an anonymous post or create a potentially fake-seeming alt account.
